# What is wrong in GDScript?

Tags: godot, multiplayer, gdscript

Could someone please help me identify what is wrong with the script Godot 3.4.4 ? The animations are not synchronized in multiplayer games, the enemy doesn't move in my viewport, I dont move in his viewport.

```
 func send_client_input(client_input):
if network.get_connection_status() == 2:
    rpc_unreliable_id(1, "client_input_update", client_input, r_id)


#   
remote func update_world_state(world_state):
if get_tree().get_rpc_sender_id() != 1:
    return
var res = scene_handler.get_node_or_null("GameScene")
if res!=null:
    res.update_world_state(world_state)
```